Cannot access methods of smart contract after returning contract object
I'm trying to call methods I've defined in my smart contract.
To start off, I'm creating this GetContract which takes in the compiled contract artifact and the contract location. This creates a contract instance which is being returned from this function.
The function is defined like so -
const fs = require("fs");

async function GetContract(web3, artifactFilename, contractHash) {
    
    const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("Contracts/Artifacts/"+artifactFilename+".json"));
    // Creating a signing account from a private key
    const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);
    // Creating a Contract instance
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        abi,
        contractHash,
    );

    // THIS CALL WORKS HERE, BUT NOT IN MAIN
    // contract.methods.set("foo").encodeABI()

    return contract
}

module.exports = GetContract

The issue I'm facing is that I can use the methods (contract.methods.set("foo")) of the created contract object in the function GetContract(). But once I try to call it from somewhere else (on the returned contract object) it complains -
const s = contract.methods.set("foo").encodeABI()
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at Object.<anonymous>

I'm not doing anything different and I'm calling it as is from main like so -
const GetContract = require('./Helpers/GetContract')

const contract = GetContract(web3, "Helloworld", process.env.HELLOWORLD_CONTRACT)
const s = contract.methods.set("foo").encodeABI()
console.log(s)

Debugging the contract returns this -
.
.
.
    _methods: {
      get: [Function (anonymous)],
      'get()': [Function (anonymous)],
      '0x6d4ce63c': [Function (anonymous)],
      set: [Function (anonymous)],
      'set(string)': [Function (anonymous)],
      '0x4ed3885e': [Function (anonymous)]
    },
.
.
.

So the method calls definitely exist, but debugging contract.methods returns undefined.
Can anyone shed light on where I'm messing up?
Thanks!

It seems like the issue is that the GetContract is an async function.
const fs = require("fs");

function GetContract(web3, artifactFilename, contractHash) {
    
    const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("Contracts/Artifacts/"+artifactFilename+".json"));
    // Creating a signing account from a private key
    const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
    web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);
    // Creating a Contract instance
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        abi,
        contractHash,
    );

    return contract
}

module.exports = GetContract


I fully don't understand why this is case, maybe the contract itself was being returned before web3.eth.Contract could fully execute?
